# Linux Mint 17.2 CodeLite Boost

Tags: c++, linux, boost

Пытаюсь подружить CodeLite и Boost, но не получается — постоянно вылетают ошибки:

> undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'
>
> undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'

Сам файл `main.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main(){
  printf("hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

Т.е. уже проверить не получается. Как исправить? Или подскажите как настроить правильно.

В линуксе недавно.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13467072/4827341

Comment: не помогает или добавляю не то и не туда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заходим в меню Project, подменю Properties... Откроется окно, где выбрать вкладку Build targets (вторая слева). В нем слева внизу ищем кнопку Build options... В появившемся окне открывам снова вторую вкладку слева Linker settings. Там в самом низу ищем кнопку Add и жмем её. В появившемся маленьком окне вписываем `boost_system` (именно так, без пробелов и расширений). После это жмем ок-ок-ок, закрывая все окна. Все, можно пробовать билдить.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Еще добавил в Settings->Environment Variables путь к либам: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

Comment: если Вы ничего не "изобретали", то скорее всего эти пути не нужны. Но Если оно заработало, то пусть так и будет.

Comment: без этих путей собирается, но при запуске пишет ошибку: `error while loading shared libraries...`, так что видимо нужны.